# Upgrading the company name of an app that has been submitted to the app store

Tags: iphone, app-store

If you first register with the app store as an individual, and then publish your program, can you later change your registration to a company? Will the program be updated to show your company name instead of your individual name?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, but it could take a couple of months to sort out the legal stuff. Check the Apple's documentations, it's the best source - sorry if I'm not really an expert...